# Send params in URL in different way?

Tags: php, zend-framework, module, routes

I don't know how to write title for this question. Anyway this is the scenario ..

I have a table like this

**Person**

```
id | username | firstname | lastname
 1 |    ab    |     Aaaa  |    Bbbb
 2 |    yz    |     Yyyy  |    Zzzz
```

I use following URL to show person profile:

```
example.com/person/profile/index?id=1   // Show person 1 profile
example.com/person/profile/index?id=1   // Show person 2 profile
```

***Here:*** `person` is module, `profile` is controller and `index` is action used to get and show user profile using param `id`

Above scenario is working perfectly.

**Question:**

Now I want to use following URLs to get user profile using usernames

```
example.com/person/profile/ab   // Show person 1 profile
example.com/person/profile/yz   // Show person 2 profile
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

If you want stay using default ZF Route, just change link to `example.com/person/profile/name/ab` and get access to name from your controller with `$this->getRequest()->getParam('name')`

Also you can make specific Route, you can find documentation here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html

Also you can configure custom route thought you config file using resources:

```
resources.router.routes.profile.route = "/person/profile/:name"
resources.router.routes.profile.defaults.controller = "person"
resources.router.routes.profile.defaults.action = "profile"
resources.router.routes.profile.reqs[] = "name"
```

Answer (score 1):

By default you don't need to do anything. Just add `/name/THENAME` to the last of the url.

Then,

1. Get the value of the name

   ```
   $name = $this -> _request -> getParam('name');
   ```
2. Use that values to extract the id from the database
3. And use it as you want